# How to load xml file with specifc paragraph by xml in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a xml file and its structure like that,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<book>
    <toc>        <tocdiv pagenum="564">
            <title>9thmemo</title>
            <tocdiv pagenum="588">
                <title>b</title>
            </tocdiv>
        </tocdiv></toc>
    <chapter><title>9thmemo</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <para>...</para></chapter>
    <chapter>...</chapter>
    <chapter>...</chapter>
</book>
```

There are several chapters in the `<book>...</book>`, and each chapter has a title, I only want to read all content of this chapter,"9thmemo"(not others)
I tried to read by following code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

filename = "result.xml"
file = minidom.parse(filename)
chapters = file.getElementsByTagName('chapter')
for i in range(10):
    print(chapters[i])
```

I only get the address of each chapter...
if I add some sub-element like `chapters[i].title`, it shows cannot find this attribute

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Try to use a more descriptive title. "How to load xml file by xml in Python?" does not say much about the actual problem,. 2) If there is an error, show us the backtrace. 3) Provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn thanks for your help, I have renew this question

Comment: Post a **valid** xml and explain what is the data you need to extract from it

Comment: @balderman hi,I upload a generilzed xml. let me know if you have any concern, thanks

Comment: @mzjn thanks again, have a look if you have time

Comment: @4daJKong Given the xml you have posted - what is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want to read all content of this chapter,"9thmemo"(not others)

The problem with the code is that it does not try to locate the specific 'chapter' while the answer code uses xpath in order to locate it.

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
   <toc>
      <tocdiv pagenum="564">
         <title>9thmemo</title>
         <tocdiv pagenum="588">
            <title>b</title>
         </tocdiv>
      </tocdiv>
   </toc>
   <chapter>
      <title>9thmemo</title>
      <para>A</para>
      <para>B</para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>...</chapter>
   <chapter>...</chapter>
</book>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
chapter = root.find('.//chapter/[title="9thmemo"]')
para_data = ','.join(p.text for p in chapter.findall('para'))
print(para_data)
```

output

```
A,B
```

Comment: @mzjn The problem with the code is that it does not try to locate the specific 'chapter' while the answer code uses xpath in order to locate it. (Answer was updated)

Comment: @baldermanba thanks for your help but it shows Exception has occurred: ParseError
syntax error: line 1, column 0, in the first code, can I load by my filename  like root = ET.fromstring(filename)

Comment: Instead of fromstring use parse